# SQL- countif correspondence from Excel

Tags: sql, db2

I have the below table, CODE1 is populated and COUNT has the values that I would like to have using a formula.

Its basically same case as an excel count if() but I need it in SQL.

```
CODE1   COUNT       
  1       2  
  1       2  
  2       3  
  2       3   
  2       3    
  3       2   
  3       2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using DB2 - IBM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is standard SQL (understood by all modern DBMS - including any up-to-date version of DB2 for z/OS or LUW):

```
select code1, 
       count(*) over (partition by code1) as cnt
from the_table
order by code1;
```

Comment: DB2 for i 7.2 does not currently support aggregate functions in [OLAP expressions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm?lang=en)

Comment: OLAP functions in general aren't supported on MySQL, either.

Answer (score 0):

First solution :

I think this SQL will combination of group by and having clause, like

```
Select CODE1,count(1) as cnt
from yourTable
group by CODE1
having count(1) > threshold
```

threshold will be your criteria and above SQL will work on all datable like MS Access, Oracle, etc.

Second solution :

Use sum with case statement, like

```
Select CODE1,sum(case when yourColumn ='anyValue' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from yourTable
```

Second solution will not work on all database.

Edit :

Now I give solution in MYSQL, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8dd5/1)

Comment: @PisoiFlo - .... I don't see how.  Neither statement will generate the result set you asked for, and one will throw a syntax error on your db.  The first statement will collapse your results, so you'd only get one row for each `code1` value (as opposed to multiple rows, each with the same count).  For the second statement, almost all RDBMSs throw a syntax error if you use an aggregate function (like `SUM`) and select columns that aren't in a `GROUP BY`.  Additionally, the case would have to be updated for each value in `code1`, which strikes me as... problematic.

Comment: Please see in SQL fiddle,sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: A) Still doesn't look like the result set the OP is going for (in the question, the count is being repeated for each instance of whatever).  B) Your outer `GROUP BY` in each subquery is pointless (you'll already have unique rows), as is the matching aggregate function.  C) It would be more idiomatic to use `COUNT` and a `WHERE` clause in this instance (and probably be faster, too, if you have a supporting index), if the results were supposed to look like that.